# GET 404 (Not Found) JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, get

```
$.get("../invoiceNumber.js", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

What i'm trying to achieve with this code snippet is: I'm trying to make $.get() request from .js file located in root/public/"said.js file" to another .js file located in the root directory (not public). The error i'm getting in my Chrome dev tools is `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/invoiceNumber.js 404 (Not Found)` Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong ? So far, i've tried every syntax i could come up with, and i tested this .get to make a request to another file in root/public/"another random file" and it works perfectly, the issue is when i try to make a get request to a file one directory up. Thanks in advance!

Also tried this code snippet:

```
$.getScript("../invoices.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(data); // Data returned
  console.log(textStatus); // Success
  console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
  console.log("Load was performed.");
});
```

And got an extra error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgwXv.png)

Comment: To request a script file you should be using [`.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) or be setting `dataType: "script"` in your `.get()` call.

Comment: Try the full path. Relative pathing is a recipe for future pain, and reversing up the file tree isn't always supported.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've just tried both `dataType: "script";` and `$.getScript("../invoiceNumber.js", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  alert("Load was performed.");
});` Same result.

Comment: @nonconvergent Also tried the full path, even renamed the file for good measure. Tried to make a get request to another file in the root directory, didn't work either >.<